# Cannot generate classes because no top-level elements with complex type were found

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xsd.exe

I am trying to create classes from a xsd file using xsd.exe, but get this:

> Warning: cannot generate classes because no top-level elements with complex type were found.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- edited with XMLSpy v2008 sp1 (http://www.altova.com) by (EMBRACE) -->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns1="http://comp.com/service/model/extension" targetNamespace="http://comp.com/service/model/extension">
    <xs:complexType name="attachment">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="fileIdentifier" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="metadataSystem">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="activityId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
            <xs:element name="from" type="xs:long" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
            <xs:element name="href" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
            <xs:element name="performers" type="xs:long" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Where I have this top-level elements?
If I add:

```
<xs:element name="attachment" type="attachment" />
```

I get this:

> Missing type "attachment"

---

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32395215/cannot-generate-classes-because-no-top-level-elements-with-complex-type-where-fo) don't help, adding element tag throw new error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot generate classes because no top-level elements with complex type where found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32395215/cannot-generate-classes-because-no-top-level-elements-with-complex-type-where-fo)

Comment: I have seen this question, but adding element tag don't help me.

Comment: I think it's not quite a duplicate, at least not with this one other question, because there is an issue with the top-level element declaration as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When declaring an element, the type must be referred to with its fully qualified name, that is, the prefix `ns1`, bound to the target namespace, was missing before `attachment` in the *type* attribute.

This is a common source of confusion, since the declaration of types (the *name* attribute) is always done with the local name only, the namespace part being always the target namespace of the schema when available.

```
<xs:element name="attachment" type="ns1:attachment" />
```

The prefix can only be omitted if the namespace of the type is declared as the default namespace with an `xmlns` attribute.

Comment: You're welcome. If you wish to read more, you may find this useful, as stackoverflow has a new documentation feature: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/xml/1593/namespaces#t=201608100756464310019